# Cannot remove controls after navigating back to page (Win 8 app)

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, controls

i have a tablet app (windows 8 app) with a starting homepage.xaml . There i have ListView binded to a ObservableCollection with UpdateSourceTrigger set to PropertyChanged ... in this list i create dynamically Panels(with delete button). When i create the button and then i click the delete button everything works fine .. the panel dissapears with nice animation. However, when i create a new panel.. then i navigate to a different page and go back to homepage, click delete to any of those panels they dont dissapear .. But if navigate again to another page and then i go back. The panel is removed. I tried to debug that collection everything looks fine. Tried to change UpdateSourceTrigger to Explicit and call it manually but no success. Thanks for help

ListView Xaml in HomePage.xaml

```
<ListView x:Name="CListView" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="40, 0, 50, 50"
                  SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="CListView_OnItemClick"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                  ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Disabled"
                  ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ClControls, ElementName=HomePageElementName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

HomePage.xaml.cs
OnItemRemove

```
 public ObservableCollection<IClControl> ClControls
    {
        get { return _clEvents; }
        set
        {
            _clEvents = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

 private async void ClControl_OnItemRemove(object sender, ClControlRemoveItemArgs e)
    {
        var control = sender as ClControl;
        if (control == null)
            return;

        var clEvent = e.ClEventInfo;

       // control.OnItemRemove -= ClControl_OnItemRemove;
        if (ClControls.Contains(control))
        {
            ClControls.Remove(control);
        }
        if (SessionHolder.Instance.ClControls.Contains(control))
        {
            SessionHolder.Instance.ClControls.Remove(control);
        }

        await clEvent.Delete();


        }
```